# SSIS Server Maintenance Job Fail

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

need your help on this: SSIS Server Maintenance Job Fail

[This job cleanup system tables using default Stored Procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGVZr.png)

The code that’s being run is an in-built part of SQL Server that is ready out-of-the-box.
From what I can gather, it cleans up the log history of what packages have been run.

```
DECLARE @role int

SET @role = (SELECT [role] FROM [sys].[dm_hadr_availability_replica_states] hars 
INNER JOIN [sys].[availability_databases_cluster] adc ON hars.[group_id] = adc.[group_id] 
WHERE hars.[is_local] = 1 AND adc.[database_name] ='SSISDB')

IF DB_ID('SSISDB') IS NOT NULL AND (@role IS NULL OR @role = 1)
EXEC [SSISDB].[internal].[cleanup_server_retention_window]
```

Which fail with this error :

Message :

> Executed as user: ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##. The DELETE
> statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
> "FK_EventMessagecontext_Operations". The conflict occurred in database
> "SSISDB", table "internal.event_message_context", column
> 'operation_id'. [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 547).

Online there are some suggestions on how to deal with this error, but I wasn’t sure how best to apply them to a default procedure.
It worries me to amend something that Microsoft have built into the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the default cleanup job that runs when SSIS is installed on SQL Server. I think something has happened to SSISDB, you should check if SSIS packages are still running normally.

SSISDB is filled with triggers and default cleanup job tries to use them when clearing old data. Sometimes it has troubles to do it's job, especially when there's a lot of data to be deleted. At that point, you can help it by removing data manually and more efficiently: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2018/12/30/clean-up-the-ssis-catalog/

Comment: Thanks @Gigga, 
well my SSIS packages run correctly there is no problem at that level, will check the link and give you my feedback. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

In our case we were missing an FK, recreated it and error went away:

```
ALTER TABLE [internal].[event_message_context]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventMessageContext_EventMessageId_EventMessages] FOREIGN KEY([event_message_id])
REFERENCES [internal].[event_messages] ([event_message_id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [internal].[event_message_context] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventMessageContext_EventMessageId_EventMessages]
GO
```